# Loop through json data and add the data to textLabel

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview

**I'm trying to take all the json data that are returning and add its content to a collection view, where the content for each index position is added to its own cell in the collection, However, only 1 cell is being created which is the first index in the array**.

[This is what it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m32PC.png)

**This where I'm performing the request to get the data**

```
func fetchSectorData(){
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/sectors-performance?apikey=\(Api.key)") else {
            fatalError("wrong sector endpoint")
        }
            
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            if let payload = data {
                guard let sectorInfo = try? JSONDecoder().decode(SectorData.self, from: payload) else {
                    print("problem decoding data")
                    return
                }
                self.sectorArray.append(sectorInfo)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionview.reloadData()
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

**This my collectionView where I'm looping through the data and appending it to the cell, However only 1 single piece of data is being appended**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "scrollId", for: indexPath) as! SectorCollectionCell
    
        let sectorPayload = sectorArray[indexPath.row].sectorPerformance
        
        for data in sectorPayload {
            cell.sectorName.text = data.sector
            cell.performance.text = data.changesPercentage
        }

        
        return cell
    }
```

**This is the data that I'm attempting to get back**

```
{
  "sectorPerformance" : [ {
    "sector" : "Aerospace & Defense",
    "changesPercentage" : "0.0241%"
  }, {
    "sector" : "Airlines",
    "changesPercentage" : "-2.0008%"
  }, {
    "sector" : "Auto Components",
    "changesPercentage" : "0.4420%"
  }, {
    "sector" : "Automobiles",
    "changesPercentage" : "-0.7118%"
  }, {
    "sector" : "Banking",
    "changesPercentage" : "-0.1773%"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: The JSON represents 1 `section` containing 4 `rows` and your code treats the section as row. It's unclear what you want to display.

Comment: `sectorArray`? Why is it an array? You have one item only, no? `let sectorPerformance = sectorArray[indexPath.section].sectorPerformance; let aSector = sectorPerformance[indexPath.row]; cell.sectorName.text = aSector.sector; cell.performance.text = changesPerrcentage`` But code of `SectorData` would help a lot, and all `UITableViewDatasource` methods too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-writing the `sectorName` and `performance` label each time in this loop. Thus, the labels only show the last values in `sectorPayload`.

```
for data in sectorPayload {
    cell.sectorName.text = data.sector             // overwrites every loop iteration 
    cell.performance.text = data.changesPercentage // overwrites every loop iteration
}
```

To solve this, it depends what you want to do. You could append all values to the one string and have the label show that appended string.

```
for data in sectorPayload {
    cell.sectorName.text = cell.sectorName.text + " \(data.sector)"
    cell.performance.text = data.changesPercentage + " \(data.sector)"
}
```

Or, you may want to generate more cells, each within a section for each `sectorPayload`. Then the cells within each section would show a `data.sector` and `data.changesPercentage` within a `sectorPayload`.

Comment: yes I'm trying to generate more cells, but only one cell is being generated at the moment.

Comment: I guess that @rohanphadte answer is the way to go. Just return a cell collection instead of writing over cell.sectorName.text and cell.performance.text.